# Generic method declaration using <TSource> in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a beginner in C#, just a question on generic method. For example:

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Where<TSource>(...)
```

so we only call this LINQ method like:

```
 var test = _context.Recipes.Where(r => !r.IsDeleted)
```

instead of

```
 var test = _context.Recipes.Where<Recipe>(r => !r.IsDeleted)
```

so why we don't just declare the generic method as

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> Where(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

The signature is

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource> (this IQueryable<TSource> source,...)
```

The reason you can call `SomeQueryable.Where(r => ...)` is because of *Type Inference*

[Generic Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods)

> **The compiler can infer the type parameters based on the method
> arguments you pass in**; it cannot infer the type parameters only from a
> constraint or return value. Therefore type inference does not work
> with methods that have no parameters. **Type inference occurs at compile
> time before the compiler tries to resolve overloaded method
> signatures**. The compiler applies type inference logic to all generic
> methods that share the same name. In the overload resolution step, the
> compiler includes only those generic methods on which type inference
> succeeded.

<sub>***Note** : There are some caveats to type inference, the compiler can only infer the types in an all-or-nothing fashion, meaning it has to infer **all** the types or I will infer **none**, the contrary is called partial inference and it's not supported in .Net.*</sub>

Comment: you are faster then me for a couple of seconds:) however I would also mark bold this part: _"Type inference occurs at compile time"_

Comment: @vasily.sib i knew this one was going to be jumped on, and thanks, done.

Comment: @Enigmativity yeah i know right, it must be because i am not working and pottering with VS 2019 all day